# IOS barcode scanning api capable of reading 3 barcode at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode

The question is seem to be a bit abstract but generally I need to develop a barcode scanning app that is capable of detecting multiple barcodes (up to 3) at the same time.

Any one know any good api for the task? (Swift or Objective C is OK). I already have an app with Zxing api but seem does not have an option for detecting multiple barcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation)! AVFoundation can scan barcodes.

Primary interest in this function:

```
#pragma mark - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate methods
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
//THIS YOU CAN USE ARRAY OF AVMetadataObjectType
    NSString *supportedBarcodeType = AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code;

    for (AVMetadataObject *barcodeMetadata in metadataObjects) {
        if ([barcodeMetadata.type isEqualToString:supportedBarcodeType]) {
            AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barcodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[self.captureLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:barcodeMetadata];
        //barcode is FIND!
            NSString *capturedBarcode = [barcodeObject stringValue];

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration method:

```
static char * const metadataOutputQueue = "metadataOutputQueue";

- (void)configureSessionWithError:(NSError **)error {    

    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    NSError *inputError = nil;
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&inputError];

    if ( nil != inputError || nil == input) {
        *error = inputError;
        return;
    }

    [self.captureSession addInput:input];

    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [self.captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create(metadataOutputQueue, NULL);
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
//THIS YOU CAN ADD ARRAY OF AVMetadataObjectType FOR DETECTING BARCODES
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code]];

    self.captureLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
    [self.captureLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [self.captureLayer setFrame:self.cameraPreviewView.layer.bounds];

    [self.cameraPreviewView.layer addSublayer:self.captureLayer];

    self.sessionConfigured = YES;
}
```

Technical Note [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2325/_index.html)! Tutorial you can find on [this site](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm reading through the tutorial and source code. But 1 problem to solve is the capability of reading multiple barcode at the same time (up to 3) (3 barcode in 1 line). Is there a way we can achieve that?

Comment: In captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObject: i think you can catch 3 barcodes. But you should remove return; after the first barcode will be scanned. And need handle other scenario for other barcode.

Comment: seem the tutorial can only catch QR. how can we catch both QR and Barcode? (1D and 2D...)?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh you can change AVMetadataObjectTypes or use Array for AVMetadataObjectTypes and scan 1D or 2D barcodes.

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh you can find all availableMetadataObjectTypes in [captureMetadataOutput availableMetadataObjectTypes];

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to modify the didOutputMetadataObjects to process multiple barcodes. Do you think should we use library (Zxing or  AVFoundation?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh I think you need use AVFoundation, because it's native and "Apple Recommends". ZXing its custom library with a lot of unnecessary.

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Did u able to achieve multiple barcode scanning at a time with AVFoundation. Could u share some insight on how to achieve this?